# Matplotlib not printing small lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.7

I need to draw some lines on a figure with a very large scale (genomic coordinates), and the lines are relatively small with respect to the scale. They should show up as just dots, essentially, and this used to work in a previous version of matplotlib. But now the small lines aren't showing up for me.

```
#make figure
fig3 = plt.figure(3)
ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(111)
#make it have big axes
ax3.set_ylim([0,506050641.0])
ax3.set_xlim([0,249250621.0])
#this line won't show up
ax3.plot([10**8,2*10**5+10**8],[height,height],linewidth = 8,solid_capstyle='round')
#this one will
ax3.plot([10**7,3.8*10**5+10**7],[height,height],linewidth=8,solid_capstyle='round')
plt.show()
```

Why?

Matplotlib version 3.0.2

Comment: Did you try `plot(xs, ys, marker='o', ...)`?

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, this is a reasonable workaround